# VBA "user-defined type not defined"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting the "user-defined type not defined" error in this line of my code

```
Sub Customer_Load()
```

This my code

```
Option Explicit
Sub Customer_Load()
  Dim CltRow As Long, LastRepRow As Lon, CustCol As Long
  With Sheet1
    If .Range("B6").Value = Empty Then
        MsgBox "Por favor, seleccione un cliente"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    CltRow = .Range("B6").Value
        
        'Clear Existing Data
        .Range("E4:G4,E6:G6,E8:G8,E10:G10,E12:G12,J4:L4, J6:L6,J8:L8,J10:L10,J12:L12").ClearContents 'Clear Customer Cells
        .Range("D17:I45").ClearContents 'Clear All Other Fields
        
        For CustCol = 1 To 12
            .Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, CustCol).Value).Value = Sheet2.Cells(CltRow, CustCol).Value
        Next CustCol
        
        .Shapes("ExistCustGrp").Visible = msoCTrue
        .Shapes("NewCustGrp").Visible = msoFalse
        .Shapes("ExistRepGrp").Visible = msoCTrue
        .Shapes("NewRepBtn").Visible = msoFalse
    End With
End Sub
```

I saw that a way to fix this error is by adding the available references, but these are the only available references I have.

[image]

Comment: You should try a basic Debug | Compile on your code until all typos are removed. Always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the third Line (Long not lon), lon doesn't exist:

```
Dim CltRow As Long, LastRepRow As Lon, CustCol As Long


Dim CltRow As Long, LastRepRow As Long, CustCol As Long
```

Also i think you don't want the data type "Long". Instead you want "Row".

Comment: Yes, now I have this error _Method 'range' of object '_Worksheet' failed_ and it shows that it's in this line of code `.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, CustCol).Value).Value = Sheet2.Cells(CltRow, CustCol).Value`